# PIVOT with LINQ from Datatable

Tags: linq

I have a Datatable populated from execution of a SQL Query .
Columns are

```
Env Group Issue
DIT  A     1
DIT  B     2
SIT  A     3
SIT  C     4
STG  D     5
```

The LINQ query should pivot as follows

```
Group  DIT SIT STG
A      1   1   0
B      1   0   0
C      0   1   0
D      0   0   1
```

Transposed, the ENV coulmns should have the count (issue)

Comment: What is exactly the question?

Comment: My apology if i was not clear. I m using C# to populate the datatable from a sql query .The  resultset which is first is the outcome of the same .I then need to customize the resultset for drawing charts ,hence instead of querying the sql server again,thought to use LINQ to get data in the various formats for usage .Hence require the ling query for pivoting the data.